# Xml file Doubled can't delate only one

Tags: android, xml

Xml file Doubled.
Activity_chart_houres_cosher become two files & When I am trying to delete one of theme both deleting.

Thanks in advance!

[image: problem pic]

Comment: which file you want to Delete if its v21 file then Go to the directry/folder and in Layout and Delete the v21

Comment: there is only one file over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have view in **Android**, and created two versions of the file, one for api21, in parenthesis next to the file.

[image]

Change the view to **Project**, and you will see them seperated, and be able to delete the one you want.

[image]

Android Studio will ask you this:

[image]

Click **NO**, otherwise it will delete both files with same name.

Hope it helps!